# How to get rid of the Aptana Ctrl-q shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, aptana

I'm using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> very often to get to the last edit location.
However, in the Aptana editor, I get a content menu where I have to choose between "Reformat comment" and "Last edit location".

This drives me nuts, I just want to jump to the last edit location

I can't find the "Reformat comment" binding in the list of shortcuts so I could delete it (or bind to another shortcut), there is only "Last edit location".

Thanks for any ideas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did it, I did it!

In the file:
{Aptana standalone location}\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\88\1.cp\bundles\source.ruble\commands\reformat_comment.rb

Change key binding to something like:

```
  cmd.key_binding = 'CONTROL+Q,Q,Q'
```

Restart IDE.

Disabling this command in "Customize workspace" didn't help.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. In Aptana Studio 3 the file location is %AptanaStudio3%\configuration\org.eclipse.osgi\bundles\373\1\.cp\bundles\source.ruble\commands\reformat_comment.rb

Comment: It looks like the location of that file is changing with every update as well as changes to that file are lost.